# Hosting ASP.net app on somee - database update from C# app

Tags: c#, .net

I have ASP.NET app with database which is updated by C# application, so database is placed on my local disc. .NET app can only read entries (changes are not allowed).
I can run my .NET app from local host (from Visual Studio or/and IIS) or other computer in network by ipaddress:port_number/page_name.aspx. Everything is working fine.

But now I would like to publish my app on somee. :) I made account and in the same project I added one simple page (just plain text) and that page can be accessed my other computers fron Internet by typing myusername.somee.com/that_simple_page_name.aspx
I found a lot of similar topics on the Internet forums so I made changes: 
- TCP/IP enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager
- exceptions ports 1433 and 1434 (UDP), 
- SQL Server Browser enabled...

I made .zip of folder created during IIS publishing (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\My_App_name) and uploaded it to the some by File Manager Upload. But when I tried to access to the page with readings from database I got error

> Server Error in '/' Application. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I believe that problem is with my connection string. My current connection string (web config file uploaded to the somee and on my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate) is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="_web_server_test.Properties.Settings.Base1ConnectionString"
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Database Somee web\Base1.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can you recognize what is the problem and how to change connection string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create the database manually in your dashboard.After creating a database the page will show you the connection string you can use in your webconfig file.

Comment: I made new database on Somee. The connection link is

Comment: I made new database (Database1Somee) on Somee. The connection link is

workstation id=Database1Somee.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=NETWORK;pwd=********;data source=Database1Somee.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=Database1Somee
When I tried to attach my database from local disc error has been generated:
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The database 'Database1Somee' cannot be opened because it is version 782.

Comment: It's because of version conflicts.Anyway you have to export your current database as a *.sql file and restore it on the server.Again from your dashboard.I don't know but it seems to me you are thinking that you can attach your local db file to a remote server and the changes will be added to your local database which is not possible.

Comment: Yes, you have right - I think that I can attach local db .mdf file just as I tried... So that is not how it should be done, thanks! But is it possible to have database stored on local hard drive and to update database from C# application and to connect my.somee.com with that database? I now that if I want to ensure access to the page that my PC must be turned on.

Comment: You can sync your local database with the remote one.But I don't know if a free service like somee will allow you to do that.

Comment: Is it possible to upload database and later to upload updated version? Let say, every day - or on some regular time intervals. Can you, please, be more specific how to connect .net application with database updated on dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you pick the right SQL version on the somee dropdown, the latest version is what worked best for me.